# how to upload image to rest API in flutter through http post method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to upload an image through the flutter via post method. and I'm using image_picker for pick file from mobile but I can't able to upload

and I have tried to send the file like FormData that also doesn't work

```
      Future<dynamic> uploadLicence(int id ,dynamic obj) async {
          FormData formdata = new FormData(); // just like JS
          formdata.add("image",obj); 
          final response = await post('Logistic/driver/LicenceImage? 
          driverId=$id', 
          formdata);
          print(response);
         //  return null;
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         final result = json.decode(response.body);
         return result;
    } else {
          return null;
   }
   }
```

after that, I just tried with this method but this also not working

```
   Future<dynamic> uploadLicence(int id, File file) async {
   final url = Uri.parse('$BASE_URL/Logistic/driver/LicenceImage? 
   driverId=$id');
   final fileName = path.basename(file.path);
   final bytes = await compute(compress, file.readAsBytesSync());

   var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
   ..files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(                                                     
  'image',bytes,filename: fileName,);
  var response = await request.send();
  var decoded = await 
  response.stream.bytesToString().then(json.decode);
  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
  print("image uploded $decoded");
  } else {
   print("image uplod failed ");
  }
  }

             List<int> compress(List<int> bytes) {
             var image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
             var resize = img.copyResize(image);
            return img.encodePng(resize, level: 1);
            }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Did you print `decoded` variable?

Comment: @ Esen Mehmet  before `decoded`  I'm  getting this error                                                            Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'compress':.)

Comment: Change this: compute(compress, file.readAsBytesSync()) => compute(compress(), file.readAsBytesSync()) . You are using compress method as reference instead using it's return value.

Comment: when I pass the `compress()` its showing error                                                                  `compress(List<int> bytes) → List<int>
The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(List<int>) → FutureOr<dynamic>`

Comment: I think problem is around `bytes` variable. Can you try to replace `bytes` variable with just this function? `compress(await file.readAsBytesSync())` I have to simulate this to give exact solution.

Comment: there is no error its not moving to another line.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `MultipartRequest`. Or you can use simply `dio` package. It's one command.

With http:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
final http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
// Additional key-values here
request.fields['sample'] = variable;
// Adding the file, field is the key for file and file is the value
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        field, await file.readAsBytes(), filename: filename);
// progress track of uploading process
final http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
print('statusCode => ${response.statusCode}');
// checking response data
Map<String, dynamic> data;
await for (String s in response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
  data = jsonDecode(s);
  print('data: $data');
}
```

Comment: @Jey can you share your example?

Comment: I have added a sample in my question

Answer (score 0):

I user this code for my project i hope work for you

```
Upload(File imageFile) async {    
var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
  var length = await imageFile.length();

  var uri = Uri.parse(uploadURL);

 var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
      filename: basename(imageFile.path));
      //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));

  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  var response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```